# MySQL 8 - Performant query for exact words match

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

We have a database table with more than 10 million entries, and we are struggling to find the best SQL query to find the entries having all the **exact words in a field irrespective of the order**. Below is the query that we have for 20 words:

```
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE (
(IFNULL(table_name.name, '') REGEXP ? AND IFNULL(table_name.name, '') REGEXP ? AND IFNULL(table_name.name, '') REGEXP ? AND 
 IFNULL(table_name.name, '') REGEXP ? AND IFNULL(table_name.name, '') REGEXP ? AND IFNULL(table_name.name, '') REGEXP ? AND
 IFNULL(table_name.name, '') REGEXP ? AND IFNULL(table_name.name, '') REGEXP ? AND IFNULL(table_name.name, '') REGEXP ? AND
 IFNULL(table_name.name, '') REGEXP ? AND IFNULL(table_name.name, '') REGEXP ? AND IFNULL(table_name.name, '') REGEXP ? AND
 IFNULL(table_name.name, '') REGEXP ? AND IFNULL(table_name.name, '') REGEXP ? AND IFNULL(table_name.name, '') REGEXP ? AND
 IFNULL(table_name.name, '') REGEXP ? AND IFNULL(table_name.name, '') REGEXP ? AND IFNULL(table_name.name, '') REGEXP ? AND
 IFNULL(table_name.name, '') REGEXP ? AND IFNULL(table_name.name, '') REGEXP ?)) ORDER BY table_name.id
```

bind variables contains boundary markers. Ex: `"\\brandom_value\\b"`. Number of bind variables will be same as number of rexexp.

Now the problem is regexp is not that performant especially on a large table and on top of it number of number of regexp increases with user typing more words. So for 50 terms we would have 50 regexp and that's a problem.

Is there any performant way to handle this use case? (We can't use fulltext index as this code is generic to all of our modules and not all of them has fulltext index created)

Comment: I assume you want to be able to filter on no particular order of those words too? E.g. the single value "I am super cool" could be filtered on by "cool" and "am" in that order?

Comment: Provide your patterns list as a rowset. CROSS JOIN it with datatable. Count non-matched pairs per value, select only those for which this count is zero.

Comment: @J.D. Yes. Ordering is not required. It's just all the exact words should be present irrespective of the order

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT ? pattern UNION ALL
              SELECT ? UNION ALL
           -- ...
              SELECT ? UNION ALL
              SELECT ? )
SELECT id
FROM datatable
CROSS JOIN cte
GROUP BY id
HAVING 0 = SUM(datatable.name NOT REGEXP cte.pattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `FULLTEXT index on` name`.

Then do `WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST ('+brandom +value' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

It will be very fast.  (Any attempt with `LIKE` or `REGEXP` will read all 10M rows; Fulltext has an inverted index of words.

There is no need for `\\b`, "word boundaries" are assumed in a Fulltext search.  You will have to construct the string to put in the `AGAINST` clause rather than using "binding".

Read the documentation on Fulltext; there are some subtleties that I have not spelled out here.

Comment: I can't use fulltext index as this code is common to all of our modules for all the fields. That is one big constraint.